# java do while does not resolve

Tags: java, do-while

i am a beginner at java and have many problems with object oriented programming. I am having trouble with the do-while loop, which tells me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
        answer cannot be resolved
        answer cannot be resolved
        at Main.main(Main.java:32)
```

But I don't really know why it can not resolve it and what that error really means. I tried to remove that do while loop, but after that it tells me that my Scanner is having a resource leak...

```
Resource leak: 'startFight' is never closed
```

I am so desperate...

Since this is my first post here, I am sorry if I make some mistakes by posting it not the way it is supposed to be. My full code is below.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Turn-Based-Battle-System App");

        String yes = "y";
        String no  = "n";
        System.out.println("Do you want to fight? (y/n)");

        do{

            Scanner startFight = new Scanner(System.in); // Creates a Object
            String answer = startFight.nextLine(); // reads user input

            if (answer.equals(yes)){
                System.out.println("The game will start now.");  // User input to start game
            }

            if (answer.equals(no)){ // user input to close game
                System.out.println("The game will be closed.");
                System.exit(0);// closes the program, if value 0, everything is ok and it is closed, if value(1) or >, then it closes because of a error
            }

        }while(!answer.equals(yes)&&!answer.equals(no));  // if user input != yes or no}
    }
}
```

Comment: You've declared `answer` within your loop, which means that as far as the code outside of that loop is concerned, it doesn't exist. I know it's confusing that the condition of the `while` doesn't see what's in the loop, but that's the way it is. What you can do is to declare `answer` outside the loop. `String answer; do{ Scanner startFighter = ...; answer = startFighter.nextLine(); ...the rest of your loop...}while(..your condition...);`

Comment: Wow first of all thank you, that solved the problem, and i think i understand now why. But now it says that when i declare my scanner inside my do loop, that a resource leak is there

Comment: It's been a while since I've written Java, but shouldn't the Scanner also be outside the do-while? Since you're recreating a scanner every while-iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java has [block scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Block_scope), meaning that a local variable defined within a block of code like `{ ... }` is only visible within that block of code. Since you declared `String answer` within the `do` block, it is not available in the `while` condition which is outside of that block.

The simplest fix is to move the declaration outside of the `do` block:

```java
String answer;
Scanner startFight = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    answer = startFight.nextLine();
    // ...
} while(!answer.equals(yes) && !answer.equals(no));

startFight.close();
```

Note that you don't have to assign a value where you declare it, so long as it's only used after it's been assigned a value.

I've also moved the Scanner outside of the loop, and used the `close` method to close it properly. The resource leak was caused by creating a new Scanner object on every iteration of the loop without closing it, when it's only necessary to create one Scanner.

Answer (score 1):

`answer` is only visible in your `do` loop block, but you shouldn't need `answer` outside that block since you terminate on `n`. I would suggest you check that there are more lines to read with `scan.hasNextLine()` and `break;` the loop on `y`. Like,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Welcome to the Turn-Based-Battle-System App");

String yes = "y", no = "n";
System.out.println("Do you want to fight? (y/n)");
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String answer = scan.nextLine();
    if (answer.equals(yes)) {
        System.out.println("The game will start now.");
        break;
    } else if (answer.equals(no)) {
        System.out.println("The game will be closed.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
// this will only be reached by running out of input or receiving a "y".
```